# Why are some Wordpress menu post_name values numbers and others slugs?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress and was looking at the database under the `wp_posts` table and noticed that some menu item rows (post_type=`nav_menu_item`) have a `post_name` value that's a number and some are a lower case text value of the menu label without white space.

I did not set these explicitly. How were they generated and how can I modify these values using the WP admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add new items to your Wordpress menu, their types may vary.

Some of those items are direct links for posts or maybe for a certain category. When that's the case, the default behaviour is to set those posts' slugs (the `post_name` in the `wp_posts` table) using solely numbers.

However, when you add a custom link to the menu, Wordpress will save its slug as the label you set for the link, or to anything closer to it, removing white spaces, creating abbreviation for longer terms when necessary and so on, thus using texts as their slugs.

That's the reason why some `post_name`s are numbers and others are texts: the origin (a post link, a category link, a custom link) of the menu item.

Now, as for changing the slug of a `nav_menu_item`, I wouldn't recommend that, since their labels are what is shown to the user in the template, not their slugs; those are irrelevant in most cases for the final user.

However, you could add, at the bottom of the `functions.php` file in your template, a code similar to the following:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_item_args', 'rename-slug' );
function rename-slug( $args ) {
    $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'the_new_slug_here'; // "the_new_slug_here" should be replaced by the new slug value you want
    return $args;
}
```

Please, be aware that [slugs must be unique](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_term_slug/#description), and that the method described above might lead to unpredictable results, [as it is pointed by the method's own original developer](https://zemez.io/wordpress/support/knowledge-base/changing-custom-post-type-slug/).